# AWS DMS replication instance and target endpoint test connection failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration, database-replication, aws-dms

I am trying to start a replication task but for that I need the test connection to work between the target endpoint (S3) and the replication instance. Here's the error:

Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: N/A, Application-Detailed-Message: N/A

They're both on the same VPC

I tried granting permission to the role but it already had.